# boost::thread_specific_ptr/cleanup vs atexit execution order

Tags: c++, ssl, pthreads

In case if multi threaded application is terminated by exit(x) or by "return" from main - which order of execution of handlers ?

1. handler registered by atexit
2. pthread_key_create/thread_specific_ptr cleanup handler (so called destructor)

or view versa ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit:

> If more than one atexit function has been specified by different calls to this function, they are all executed in reverse order as a stack (i.e. the last function specified is the first to be executed at exit).